# Can't access location

Tags: android, android-location

I'm trying to access the location and display the latitude and longitude in textviews onClick of a button.

Here's my code:

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView textView, textView1;
    Button button;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView1 = findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        button = findViewById(R.id.button);
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    boolean enableOnly = true;
                    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                    List<String> providers = locationManager.getProviders(enableOnly);

                    for (String provider : providers) {
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                            if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                                Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
                                if (location != null) {
                                    textView.setText((int) location.getLatitude());
                                    textView1.setText((int) location.getLatitude());
                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "sorry", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                    }
            }

            });

    }
}
```

The AVD on which i'm testing is on Android 8.1
I have also set the user-permission in the AndroidManifest to access the coarse and fine location. Location permissions are also granted to the app.

But whenever i click the button nothing happens.
Please help me out.

Comment: Location is not null, checkSelfPermission doesn't return false @BkSantiago

Comment: try getting location under 
   onLocationChanged(Location location) method

Comment: set location from avd settings

Answer (score 0):

```
if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == 
PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && 
checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == 
PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    //do your task
}
```

also this code will work only for above marshmallow devices as u have mentioned

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
LocationManager mLocationManager;
Location myLocation = getLastKnownLocation();

private Location getLastKnownLocation() {
    mLocationManager = (LocationManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    List<String> providers = mLocationManager.getProviders(true);
    Location bestLocation = null;
    for (String provider : providers) {
        Location l = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        if (l == null) {
            continue;
        }
        if (bestLocation == null || l.getAccuracy() < bestLocation.getAccuracy()) {
            // Found best last known location: %s", l);
            bestLocation = l;
        }
    }
    return bestLocation;
}
```

Comment: i bet in testing it will return null 70% of  time

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I didn't see you've got the permission.
Now use setUpGPS whenever the permission granted:

```
 LocationManager locationManager;

void setUpGPS() {
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        return;
    }
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(locationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            location.getLatitude();
            location.getLongitude();
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

        }
    });

}
```

onLocationChanged method has two methods: getLatitude and getLongitude. These are user's location points. You can pass them in the double variables and use them.